# Нахождение всех вхождений подмассива в массив за О(N)

Tags: алгоритм

Передо мной стоит достаточно тривиальная задача: найти все вхождения подмассива в массив. Стандартным методом (на каждой итерации по элементам первоначального массива берём K элементов и сравниваем полученный массив значений с искомым подмассивом длиной K) поиск вхождений в худшем случае занимает O((N-K+1)*K), что приемлемо на небольших входных данных.

Но обработать, увы, таким образом мне предстоит данные внушительные. Я подумал над тем, чтобы реализовать поиск вхождений за О(N), т.е. каким-то образом сохраняя данные о найденных вхождениях и сверяя их на каждом новом шаге. По аналогии с поиском единственного вхождения, где мы сохраняем индекс и счётчик, увеличивая его или обнуляя в зависимости от текущего элемента первоначального массива, и возвращаем сохранённый индекс, когда счётчик достиг длины искомого подмассива.

Помогите, пожалуйста, развить сей алгоритм для нахождения **всех** вхождений заданного подмассива, а не только **первого**, так как мне в голову лезут какие-то бредовые идеи

---

UPD: Пример входных/выходных данных

- Массив: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
- Подмассив: [1, 2, 3]
- Выходные данные: [0, 6, 9]

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Буду очень признателен

Comment: не не получится... я думал отсортировать, но по всей видимости у вас элементы в массиве имеют определённый порядок, и имеются повторяющиеся элементы.

Comment: напишите пример данных с правильным выводом, так как непонятна структура данных и результат который вы хотите получить

Comment: так как там есть разные варианты, например с сохранением порядка, или без сохранения. и вообще непонятно что такое два вхождения, например...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Обновил вопрос

Comment: O(n)? Нереально. Необходимо проверять каждую потенциальную подпоследовательность на полное вхождение, т.е. получаем O(n*m), где m - количество найденных кандидатов на вхождение. Поскольку в пределе m = n - k + 1, где k - длина подпоследовательности, имеем O(n^2).

Comment: А что должно вернуть при `Массив = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] Подмассив = [1, 1, 1];`?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 и т.д.] хД

Comment: На самом деле самый простой алгоритм достаточно быстро будет работать, в среднем за O(N), но в худшем (но это очень редко) за O(N^2).

Comment: А зачем вам на худший случай опираться-то, в реальных случайных данных это очень маловероятно.

Comment: А вам в каком контексте надо, если например задана фиксированная изначальная последовательность и надо много раз по ней искать заданные слова, я знаю как ускорить работу. Один раз будет входной массив подготавливать, а потом каждый поиск нового слова быстро делать будет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Последовательность, увы, фиксированной не является) Я в памяти копаюсь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это базовый алгоритм, но он в большинстве ситуациях будет работать за O(N) операций. Понять это можно через просмотр условия внутреннего цикла, до второй итерации будет очень редко доходить, а тем более до третий и далее.

Худший случай достигается при ситуации `base = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] find = [1,1,1,1]`. Но вы думаете что есть алгоритм, который в такой ситуации сработает быстрее? Ну может быть и есть, но подобные 'долгие' ситуации очень редки, если брать все возможности ситуаций. И возможно даже если асимптотически такой алгоритм для таких ситуаций будет работать быстрее, то скорее всего из-за его сложности он будет работать медленнее на базовых ситуациях, что в результате сделает его медленнее в среднем. Вообщем я бы не стал дальше пытаться его оптимизировать.

```js
var base = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3];
var find = [1, 1, 2, 3];
var rez = [];
var yes;

var max = base.length - find.length;

for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
  yes = true;

  for (var j = 0; j < find.length; j++) {
    if (base[i + j] != find[j]) {
      yes = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (yes) {
    rez.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(rez);
```

**Обновлено**

Для максимально быстрого поиска необходимо использовать конечные автоматы.

Смотрим [алгоритм Ахо — Корасик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA).

Comment: В первом абзаце вопроса я как раз описал, что на данный момент использую именно такой алгоритм) Но за то, что будущим поколениям расписали его - плюс)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov не факт что есть алгоритмы быстрее для худшего варианта

Comment: Вообще-то алгоритм есть, нам про него на первом курсе говорили на матлогике, надо использовать конечные автоматы. Такой алгоритм учитывает повторяющиеся последовательности в паттернах. Но это не вопрос для стака. Это реально сложный алгоритм, который можно не один день делать а может и не одну неделю. Как говорят Regex-ы при правильной реализации на таких принципах работают.

Comment: Такой алгоритм составляет по паттерну который надо найти конечный автомат для поиска, и ищет уже используя его. При желании можно написать, но как говорил выше это больше вопрос для фриланс сайта.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Ловите - https://nauchforum.ru/studconf/tech/xvi/4308

Comment: И вот это - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Ахо_—_Корасик

Comment: О, шикарно! Реально интересная вещь, большое спасибо!

Comment: @Kir_Antipov если вам мой ответ помог, можете отметить его.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
var sub = [1, 2, 3];
var res = [];

var j = 0;
var start = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //console.log(i, arr[i], j, sub[j], start);
  if (start == -1) {
    if (arr[i] == sub[j]) {
      start = i;
      j++;
    } else {
      start = -1;
      j = 0;
    }
  } else {
    if (arr[i] == sub[j]) {
      if (j == sub.length - 1) {
        res.push(start);
        start = -1;
        j = 0;
      } else {
        j++;
      }
    } else {
      start = -1;
      j = 0;
      if (arr[i] == sub[j]) {
        start = i;
        j++;
      }
    }
  }
}
// TODO: fix logic to account for sub consisting of one element

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Надо добавить ещё одно TODO: если, скажем, хотя бы первые два элемента массива идентичны, то сие дело может отрабатывать не совсем верно. Представьте такую ситуацию: исходный массив = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Подмассив = [2, 2, 3, 4, 5]. res останется пустым в ходе выполнения, хотя должен бы содержать в себе элемент 2)

Comment: Ну да ладно, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Неверно работает при var `arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
var sub = [1, 1, 2];` находит только одно решение из двух

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Да, я об этом же пишу. Работает корректно в том случае, если подмассив не содержит двух и более подряд идущих одинаковых значений. Но хоть что-то)